# Angels laughing when you look up

Tags: mysticism-kabbalah

Apparently it says in Sefer HaChassidim that when you daven looking up at the ceiling, the angels are laughing at you. Anyone have any idea what this means exactly?

Comment: Probably means that it expresses naiveté when a person thinks Hashem is up (i. e. dwelling in a particular direction) when Hashem is actually everywhere and nowhere at once. A person looking up during davening isn't better than a person looking sideways or downwards (unless he's looking at his siddur).

Comment: @Harel13 Hashem is not nowhere. And S"A says you should look downward but direct your thoughts upward during davening.

Comment: @shmosel read about the concept of tzimtzum sometime. It's a chassidic concept but its roots lay in many older concepts. Tzimtzum is very much Hashem's removal of Himself from material, mortal reality to allow us to live with free will. And so, yes, Hashem is also nowhere. What's S"A?

Comment: @Harel13 Shulchan Aruch Orach Chaim 95. Tzimtzum only creates the illusion of absence. Hashem is as present as He ever was. אתה הוא עד שלא נברא העולם, אתה הוא משנברא העולם